# Is there a line iteration for Eigen matrix so that I can iterate through the matrix line by line?

Tags: matrix, iterator, eigen, eigen3

The question is about [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). Being used to iterator in C++, I think it is natural to expect that there is an line (or column) iterator for Eigen matrix so that I can iterate through the matrix line by line, e.g., something like the following:

```
Matrix4f m;
auto it = m.line_cbegin();
while(it != m.line_cend()) {
  ...
  some_operation(*it)  //*it is expected to be a Vector4d object
  ...
  it++;
}
```

So is there any such iterator available in Eigen? I have checked some of Eigen documentation but did not find any, so I ask here in case I missed it. Thank you.

Comment: `*it` would of course be a `RowVector4d`-like object (it would be a read/writable view to the corresponding row), when written as in @ggael's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the [head](http://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/default.tar.bz2) of Eigen's devel branch, then simply do as the [doc](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSTL.html#title2) says:

```
for(auto row : m.rowwise())
  some_operation(row);
```

Of course this example means that you can also call `begin()/end()` or `cbegin()/cend()` on `m.rowwise()`.

Comment: Thank you! It's a wonderful idea. I have taken the insomnia medicine so I have to go to bed now. But I will check this technique tomorrow. Don't you worry, it is highly likely I will accept your answer with an up-vote. Thank you again, ggael.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the doc link. I'm so glad to see that iterator is going to be added in the next version of Eigen. Looking forward to it.